# SAME70 USB CDC does not open endpoints correctly

Tags: usb, usb-device, atmel

I downloaded the stock [USB CDC echo demo](https://start.atmel.com/#examples/usb) for ATSAME70. The device correctly enumerates over USB. I can see ttyACM0 appearing in the OS but later the demo gets stuck waiting for `cdcdf_acm_is_enabled()`.

I traced the execution of the ASF USB stack by adding printfs:

```
cdcf_acm_ctrl, ctrl = 1
cdcdf_acm_disable returned 0
usb_d_ep_init, ep = 0
_usb_d_dev_ep_init ep = 0, epn = 0
cdcf_acm_ctrl, ctrl = 1
cdcdf_acm_disable returned 0
usb_d_ep_init, ep = 0
_usb_d_dev_ep_init ep = 0, epn = 0
cdcf_acm_ctrl, ctrl = 0
usb_d_ep_init, ep = 130
_usb_d_dev_ep_init ep = 130, epn = 2
usb_d_ep_init returned 0
usb_d_ep_init, ep = 1
_usb_d_dev_ep_init ep = 1, epn = 1
usb_d_ep_init returned 0
usb_d_ep_init, ep = 129
_usb_d_dev_ep_init ep = 129, epn = 1
usb_d_ep_init returned -20
cdcdf_acm_enable returned -20
```

I can see that the stack initializes HW endpoint 2 first (endpoint address 130 in the stack), then HW endpoint 1 (using endpoint address 1), and then again HW endpoint 1 but using endpoint address 129. This makes `usb_d_ep_init()` return `USB_ERR_REDO` and CDC is never enabled.

I did not change the config or anything else (apart from printfs) in the stock demo. How can I fix the double initialization by ASF USB stack?